# htaccess file redirecting too mant times

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I want to redirect my site `example.com` to `https://example.com`.

I have uploaded an `.htaccess` file to my server with the following code:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE`
```

However, when I hit it to the server, it giving error on browser as it redirects you too many times.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Let's trust you on the fact that "EARN UP TO 10% per Month as Investment Income" isn't fishing...

Answer (score 0):

Add the www if not present and redirect to the secure link.

```
# If www is not present add it

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Check for the use of httpS and if it isn't present redirect to the secure address.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [L]
```

Put it all together and you get:

```
# If www is not present add it

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [L]
```